# DotCMS with spring security authentication in Grails application

Tags: grails, spring-security, dotcms

We have a grails application with "standard" spring security authentication. We have integrated this application into dotCMS. What is missing is the dotCMS authentication. Is it somehow possible to configure DotCMS to use the User/Role spring security system that I already have?
DotCMS has already its system of Users and Roles. I am reading now this page, mentioning that it is possible to develop custom "pluggable" authentication mechanisms: http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/pluggable-authentication.
I would appreciate it if knowledgable developers could share their opinions on this.
I am not sure if the question is too "abstract"

Answer (score 1):

You can build a cas to server both grails and Dotcms.
Both of two apps have the well done cas module.
Only different is cas - LDAP in dotcms is not free.