# How to integrate Spring Security with dotCMS

Tags: gradle, spring-security, dotcms

I need to deny unauthenticated users to access some website pages. I know that dotCMS roles can do that, but i need to guarantee that Spring do the same job.
It's possible apply Spring Security in dotCMS?
I tried to implement some security with Java Config but with no success.
I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633040/dotcms-with-spring-security-authentication-in-grails-application) but it wasn't conclusive to me.
I didn't find any other example of this on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I am not (by any means) an expert with Spring Security, but it seems I would add the Spring Security filter (via a plugin) to dotCMS before the dotCMS filters and use it to secure your dotcms via urls.  You might want to write a custom filter that checks the dotCMS roles for the proper permissions.  Depends on your case.